# Code to show locally stored CSV file in a webpage using HTML & AJAX jquery NOT Working

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, csv

Here is my index.html for the code. The following code is showing up in the browser only till the button extent. After that, it's not working the way it should be.

It should load the whole CSV file which is stored in the same folder as index.html and show it in the webpage. I can't identify the issue with it. Need help with this. Thank you.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <h1 align="center">CSV File to HTML Table</h1><br />
    <div align="center">
      <button type="button" name="load_data" id="load_data" class="btn btn-info">Load Data</button>
    </div><br />
    <div id="employee_table"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#load_data').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "FGExport - LEVI.csv",
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(data) {
        var employee_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
        var table_data = '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">';
        for (var count = 0; count < employee_data.length; count++) {
          var cell_data = employee_data[count].split(",");
          table_data += '<tr>';
          for (var cell_count = 0; cell_count < cell_data.length; cell_count++) {
            if (count === 0) {
              table_data += '<th>' + cell_data[cell_count] + '</th>';
            } else {
              table_data += '<td>' + cell_data[cell_count] + '</td>';
            }
          }
          table_data += '</tr>';
        }
        table_data += '</table>';
        $('#employee_table').html(table_data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I also tried async: false and datatype: "json", didn't worked :/.

Comment: What debugging have you done? There's *a lot* of things that can go wrong with an AJAX request. The first step is to open devtools and check the console for errors.

Comment: Are you trying to run it with or without a webserver? In either case "url" seems incomplete.

Comment: I have tried debugging through chrome and got breakpoints from "$('#load_data').click(function() {" this line to "success: function(data) {". Also no I am trying to run it without a server, like simple running the index file to the chrome.

Comment: also @ghitesh could you please specify the better way to put the address in the "URL" part.